# Imposm add new country to existing database

Tags: imposm

I've imported several countries to PostGIS by use of IMPOSM.
The written cache files are not present anymore.

Let's say I'm in the need to add/import another country without losing all countries already in the database.

What I tried is to create the cache for the new country

```
./imposm import -mapping mapping.yml -read sweden.pbf -appendcache
```

and import it

```
./imposm import -mapping mapping.yml -write -connection postgis://user:pass@localhost/osm
```

which will clear all data in the database. Also from what I see the docs only explain how to update an existing country with a diff file? https://imposm.org/docs/imposm3/latest/tutorial.html#updating

How can I import new countries but keep already existing?